# Proper way to use SFINAE struct defintions

Tags: c++, sfinae

For educative reasons, I was playing around with the SFINAE behavior of C++ and building my own version of `std::enable_if` in a rather simplified form. I noticed different behavior when using slightly different implementation details though:

Implementation as incomplete type:

```
template <bool C, typename> struct enable_if; // incomplete type
template <typename T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Implementation as empty type:

```
template <bool C, typename> struct enable_if {}; // empty type
template <typename T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

On g++ (4.8.1 and 4.3.2) both versions compile and behave the same way. MSVC 2008 seems to only accept the definition as an empty type.

Are both definitions valid C++, and should they be equivalent in behavior?

Comment: MSVC 2008 shouldn't be used as a reference, ever.

Comment: Unless C++11 changed things, I believe that non-existent types generated a non-SFINAE eligible error, while empty type did.  I don't know why I believe this, so don't trust it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standard, § 14.8.2:

> Type deduction may fail for the following reasons:
>       [...]
>       Attempting to use a type in a nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id
>       when that type does not contain the specified member, or the specified 
>       member is not a type where a type is required [...]

Both cases are handled in the same sentence, so from my understanding it really should not make a difference - both implementations should be equivalent.

Comment: Does this apply for C++03 and C++11?

Comment: Note that the quoted passage is only a *comment* in the Standard.